# What's the special name for $N \rtimes \textrm{Aut}(N)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology, semidirect-product, automorphism-group

I was in class today, and the teacher mentioned that the semidirect product given by $N \rtimes \textrm{Aut}(N)$ has a special name, but I couldn't understand what he said well enough to write it down. Does anyone know what it's called, what it's useful for, and where I could learn more about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This type of semidirect product is the so-called holomorph of the group $N$ and (at least the name) was introduced by Burnside. Apparently (after a quick google search), the following problem/question is the origin of the holomorph: "Is it possible to include any given group  as a normal subgroup in some other group so that all the automorphisms of $N$ are restrictions of inner automorphisms of this large group?"

See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13897/uses-of-the-holomorph-holg-g-rtimes-autg) for more information and more uses.

Comment: Thank you, that's it!

Answer (score 1):

It's called the outer semi-direct product.

Comment: I don't think the op is asking what the symbol means, but rather how this type of semidirect product is called as it has a special name.

Comment: The teacher may have been distinguishing between inner and outer  semidirect products but, on balance, I think your interpretation is most likely to be correct.

Comment: Thanks for the help S. Dolan, but ThorWittich was correct - I know what semidirect products are and was looking for the specific name for the product.